# appcompat-v7:23.1.0 and mediarouter-v7:22.0.0

Tags: android

I have an exceptiuon I want to work on the SDK level 23 so on one of my depedencies I get an error:

```
with: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 23.0.0, 22.0.0. Examples include com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0 and com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:22.0.0 less... (Ctrl+F1)  There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that
> are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is
> compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not
> the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your
> targetSdkVersion.)
```

And that's true on the librairies I have: mediarouter-v7:22.0.0

Do I have to delete this last ?

Comment: Change it to the same version?

Comment: @MuratK. It is a solution ? How I do if I want to use SDK 23

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same version numbers. Change your `mediarouter-v7:22.0.0` to `com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:23.0.0`

See [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html#v7-mediarouter) for an overview of the support packages.